# CoreLocation warning: incompatible type

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location, incomplete-type

I get the following error warning:

```
Passing 'MyCLController *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<CLLocationManagerDelegate>'
```

... on this line:

```
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
```

If I remove the line the whole location update process fails. So it is import but also includes an error.

The location updates work smoothly but I have no clue how to get rid of this message ...

Must have something to do with the "new" Xcode 4 ...

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Has more to do with the fact you have ARC turned on than with XCode 4. Can you show in your original question how you have your `delegate` declared in your .h interface file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the delegate protocol in your interface definition:

```
@interface MyCLController : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
...
@end
```

Comment: Jep. That was it. Thanks a ton! :)